# ZSH - How can I join an array using the colon ":" character/escape colon character?

Tags: zsh

I don't know how to escape colons when using the zsh [j:string:](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) array expansion sequence.

In my ~/.zshrc I find it pleasing to build up my PATH as an array.

```
path_array=(
  /sbin
  /usr/sbin
  $HOME/brew/bin
  /bin
  /usr/bin
  /usr/local/bin
  /opt/X11/bin
)

#https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23208/building-paths-robustly/23241#23241
#export PATH=${(j:::)path_array}
```

There are plenty of examples of how to join an array on other characters but unfortunately I can't see how to escape the character ':' so I can use it in this sequence.

The result is : `zsh: error in flags`

Using another character ('|') it works fine

```
echo ${(j:|:)path_array}

/sbin|/usr/sbin|/Users/mf/brew/bin|/bin|/usr/bin|/usr/local/bin|/opt/X11/bin
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Re `zsh: error in flags`: This one is easy. You can use *any other* delimiter in your parameter expansion flags:

```
$ arr=(/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /usr/sbin /bin)
$ print -R ${(j|:|)arr}
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin
```

Your bigger problem is you shouldn't need to do this in the first place. Zsh specifically has a lowercase `path` variable which is the array counterpart of the scalar `PATH`. Setting one automatically updates the other. See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-path. (Similarly there are `cdpath`, `fpath`, `mailpath`, `manpath`, etc.) Here's an example:

```
$ path=(/usr/bin /bin)
$ print -R $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin
$ path=(/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /usr/sbin /bin)
$ print -R $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin
$ PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
$ print -R $path
/usr/bin /bin
```

You get the idea.

As an aside, I also recommend

```
typeset -gU path
```

to remove duplicates, because it's not uncommon to insert duplicate entries into `path` (when you insert paths the right way: prepend to the existing array).

Comment: What if I want to join the array with a delimiter inputed by the user? Variable expansion seems not working here: `print -R ${(j|$delimiter|)input}`

Comment: @BruceSun - add a 'p': `print -R ${(pj|$delimiter|)input}`.